# Limit without L'Hopital rule - help!

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I need help in the following problem:

> $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x - x \cos x}{\sin^2 2 x}.$$
> L'Hopital has not yet given in my Calculus I class at college, so there has to be a way to solve it without L'Hopital, but I can't find it.

My proof:

> $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x - x \cos x}{\sin^2 2 x} = \frac{x.(1-cosx)(1+cosx)}{sin^2(2x).(1+cosx)}=\frac{x.sin^2x}{(1+cosx).sin^2(2x)}$$
> $$lim_{x\to0}\frac {x - x \cos x}{\sin^2 2 x}= \frac{x}{1+cosx}. [{\frac{sinx}{sin(2x)}]^2}$$
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac {x - x \cos x}{\sin^2 2 x}=\frac{0}{2}.\frac{1}{4}=0$$

Comment: Hint: Multiply and divide by $4x^2$. Then apply the two trigonometric fundamental limits

Comment: $$\frac{x-x\cos x}{\sin^22x}=\frac{4x^2}{\sin^22x}\cdot\frac{x(1-\cos x)}{4x^2}.$$Can you complete the proof?

Comment: I found it, Diego! I made a mistake before and the answer was 0/0. I have just recalculated it, a few seconds before your comment hahaha thank you!

Comment: Use $1-\cos x=2\sin^2 (x/2).$